# How to make Monaco editor show \n or \" in the editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I have the following problem, I want Monaco editor to literally show me the characters as I passed them in the value, to show **\n** and **\"**. But it couldn't, any suggestions?

this is my code

```
editor_source = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('editor_source'), {
    value: "{\n  \"message\": \"¡Hello World!\", \n  \"status\": \"successful\"\n}",
    language: 'plaintext',
    wordWrap: 'on',
    tabSize: 2,
    indentSize: 2,
  })
```

This is what it looks like in the editor

```
{
  "message": "¡Hello World!", 
  "status": "successful"
}
```

[monaco-editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgKB4.png)

and I want it to show like this

```
{\n  \"message\": \"¡Hello World!\", \n  \"status\": \"successful\"\n}
```

thank you very much for your help

Comment: You just need a bunch more escapes…?! `"{\\n \\\"message\\\" ..."`

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(value)` and it will include all the escaped characters as a string

Comment: @JeremyFiel It will also include extra quotes…